# Emacs not showing filename

Tags: configuration, emacs

Where once was the filename of the file now there is a black stripe, preventing me to see what I'm editing.

[image]

To clarify a bit, it's that black stripe between "F1" and "All", when I did the screenshot I was editing my .emacs file.

I'm running GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (with the `-nw` flags) on Ubuntu 11.04.

I've tried executing `emacs -q`, the graphical interface pops up and the file name is correctly readable.

Here is my .emacs:

```
(defconst user-init-dir '~/Dropbox/emacs)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/emacs")

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/clojure/clojure-mode")
(require 'clojure-mode)

(eval-after-load "slime" 
  '(progn (slime-setup '(slime-repl))))

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/emacs/slime")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)

;;line numbers
(global-linum-mode)
;;parens highlight
(show-paren-mode 1)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
  '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))

;;steve yegge's js mode http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/wiki/InstallationInstructions
(setq load-path (append (list (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/emacs/js2")) load-path))
(autoload 'js2-mode "js2" nil t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js$" . js2-mode))

;;save how the session was when i exited http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

EDIT: Sadly this seems to be bigger than I thought, seems to be a wider configuration of colors which somehow I changed, I'm almost certain of this because now `man` does not show flags letters for the switches in its pages and completions in emacs are not shown.

Anyway, this just for the sake of completeness, maybe I'll open a new question on this after I've searched a bit more...

Comment: It might help to know platform context when you saw this. OS, terminal emulation (if any), version of emacs, etc. OTOH, I've never seen anything like it, so maybe context won't help.

Comment: With more information this might be better off on Super User or Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've added the OS and Emacs version, what else might be needed?

Comment: Do you have the same effect is you run `emacs -q`? Is this the Gtk version (`emacs23-x`), the Lucid version (`emacs23-lucid`) or the tty version (`emacs23-nox`)? If Gtk, did you change your Gnome color theme? If Lucid, do you have X resources related to Emacs? If tty, does it happen in all terminal emulators?

Comment: I've edited my answer, also I think it's the `emacs23-nox` version, in Synaptic I can see `emacs` `emacs23` and `emacs23-nox` as installed.

Comment: Is Emacs executing in a terminal or in its own window? Since `emacs -q` is fine, the problem is in your `~/.emacs` (or in one of the files it loads); post this file. You've apparently configured some face to be black on black.

Comment: Emacs is executing in its own windows. I think the .emacs is fine, do you know where else I could look for the problem?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni Start `emacs -q ~/.emacs` and repeatedly press `Ctrl+Alt+E` `Ctrl+Alt+X` to execute its statements in sequence until the color changes.

Comment: Now I'm at work and don't have my environment, but I've used my emacs here and the filename is showing up with no problem, I'll try that procedure this evening, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer name is in the `mode-line-buffer-id` face, applied above the `mode-line` face. By default, on a dark background in a terminal, `mode-line` is in black on white and `mode-line-buffer-id` is bold; maybe you accidentally gave it a black foreground.

Comment: Ok, I've never did this on purpose, but maybe I did it without knowing it :P, do you know where I could check for this?

Comment: @Alberto Zaccagni: Do M-x customize-face RET mode-line-buffer-id RET

Comment: Your command above helped me a lot, the problem can be solved in that form, thank you very much :)